# Move information from one variable to another (same page)

Tags: php

Since i have many diffrent workers on my workkey and i just want to print every work once. I Though of doin a check like this.
At the end of the loop i wanna save the value from workkey. So before every print i will check, If the new workkey is diffrent from the last one = Dont print.

```
$counter = 0;
while(db2_fetch_row($queryexe)) {
$work = db2_result($queryexe, 'workkey');
$fname = db2_result($queryexe, 'fname');
$lname = db2_result($queryexe, 'lname');

if ($workkey != $saveworkkey){
    $counter = 0;
 }

if ($counter < 1){ 
    print ( some stuff)
    print ( some stuff)
    print ( some stuff)

 }
$workkey = $saveworkkey;
$counter++;
    }
```

Comment: And what is the question then?

Comment: how can i move $workkey to $saveworkkey? i did like  $workkey = $saveworkkey; but it doesnt help

Comment: $workkey is NULL where you assign the value?? also $saveworkkey; Null

Comment: `$saveworkkey = $workkey;` ?

Comment: workkey i get from database

Comment: yes that fking code did it.. thank you epodax

Answer (score 0):

What I do to solve the issue is to add all values to an array with the key as array key. This way, even if there are duplicates they will overwrite eachother.

```
$workers = array()
while ($record = db2_fetch_row($queryexe)) {
    $workers[$record['workkey']] = $record;
}
```

To print your values you can simply foreach

```
foreach ($workers as $worker) {
    // print worker
}
```